# Neural Network outputs same values for All Inputs

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a ConvNet model. It is outputting the exact same values for all cases of forward propagation.

Originally, it didn't happen during training and only evaluation because the dropout rate was set to 1 and there was no learning rate. This lead me to believe that I was restoring the model incorrectly, However, I decided to test it during training by removing the dropout and setting the learning zero. When I outputted the softmax values, every one of them is constant.

I then analyzed the images and labels that were displayed through tensorboard, and every one of them seemed to be changing, there was definitely changing data.

So the problem is not with the inputs but definitely with the forward propagation itself, though I am not able to see where it went wrong.

```
def weight_variable(shape):
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        initial = tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.00125)
        return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape = shape)
        return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv(images, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(images, W, strides = [1, 1, 1, 1], padding = 'SAME')

def forward_propagation(images, dropout_value2):
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        conv1_feature = weight_variable([8, 8, 3, 16])
        conv1_bias = bias_variable([16])
        image_matrix = tf.reshape(images, [-1, 800, 800, 3])
        conv1_result = tf.nn.relu(conv(image_matrix, conv1_feature) + conv1_bias)
        _activation_summary(conv1_result)

        conv1_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1_result, ksize = [1, 2, 2, 1], strides = [1, 2, 2, 1], padding = 'SAME')
        norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(conv1_pool, 4, bias = 1.0, alpha = 0.001 / 9.0, beta = 0.75, name = 'norm1')

        conv2_feature = weight_variable([3, 3, 16, 64])
        conv2_bias = bias_variable([64])
        conv2_result = tf.nn.relu(conv(norm1, conv2_feature) + conv2_bias)
        _activation_summary(conv2_result)

        conv2_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2_result, ksize = [1, 2, 2, 1], strides = [1, 2, 2, 1], padding = 'SAME')
        norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(conv2_pool, 4, bias = 1.0, alpha = 0.001 / 9.0, beta = 0.75, name = 'norm2')

        conv3_feature = weight_variable([3, 3, 64, 128])
        conv3_bias = bias_variable([128])
        conv3_result = tf.nn.relu(conv(norm2, conv3_feature) + conv3_bias)
        _activation_summary(conv3_result)

        conv3_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv3_result, ksize = [1, 2, 2, 1], strides = [1, 2, 2, 1], padding = 'SAME')
        norm3 = tf.nn.lrn(conv3_pool, 4, bias = 1.0, alpha = 0.001 / 9.0, beta = 0.75, name = 'norm3')

        conv4_feature = weight_variable([3, 3, 128, 256])
        conv4_bias = bias_variable([256])
        conv4_result = tf.nn.relu(conv(norm3, conv4_feature) + conv4_bias)
        _activation_summary(conv4_result)
        conv4_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv4_result, ksize = [1, 2, 2, 1], strides = [1, 2, 2, 1], padding = 'SAME')
        norm4 = tf.nn.lrn(conv4_pool, 4, bias = 1.0, alpha = 0.001 / 9.0, beta = 0.75, name = 'norm4')

        conv5_feature = weight_variable([3, 3, 256, 512])
        conv5_bias = bias_variable([512])
        conv5_result = tf.nn.relu(conv(norm4, conv5_feature) + conv5_bias)
        _activation_summary(conv5_result)
        conv5_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv5_result, ksize = [1, 2, 2, 1], strides = [1, 2, 2, 1], padding = 'SAME')
        norm5 = tf.nn.lrn(conv5_pool, 4, bias = 1.0, alpha = 0.001 / 9.0, beta = 0.75, name = 'norm5')

        perceptron1_weight = weight_variable([25 * 25 * 512, 256])
        perceptron1_bias = bias_variable([256])
        flatten_dense_connect = tf.reshape(norm5, [-1, 25 * 25 * 512])
        compute_perceptron1_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(flatten_dense_connect, perceptron1_weight) + perceptron1_bias)
        _activation_summary(compute_perceptron1_layer)

        perceptron2_weight = weight_variable([256, 256])
        perceptron2_bias = bias_variable([256])

        compute_perceptron2_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(compute_perceptron1_layer, perceptron2_weight) + perceptron2_bias)
        perceptron3_weight = weight_variable([256, 100])
        perceptron3_bias = bias_variable([100])

        compute_perceptron3_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(compute_perceptron2_layer, perceptron3_weight) + perceptron3_bias)

        perceptron4_weight = weight_variable([100, 50])
        perceptron4_bias = bias_variable([50])

        compute_perceptron5_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(compute_perceptron3_layer, perceptron4_weight) + perceptron4_bias)

        perceptron5_weight = weight_variable([50, 4])
        perceptron5_bias = bias_variable([4])

        dropout = tf.nn.dropout(compute_perceptron5_layer, dropout_value2)
        result1 = tf.matmul(dropout, perceptron5_weight) + perceptron5_bias
        _activation_summary(result1)
        return result1

def error(forward_propagation_results, labels):
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int64)
        cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=forward_propagation_results, labels=labels)
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

        tf.add_to_collection('losses', cost)
        tf.summary.scalar('LOSS', cost)
        return cost

def train(cost):
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        train_loss = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.01).minimize(cost)
        return train_loss
```

Comment: Can you try something like the [TensorFlow debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger) for tracking down the layer where this is happening? It sounds like it might just be a particularly bad case of dead ReLUs.

Comment: I have suspected that it may be dead relu's, however it outputs the same values from the very first iteration using stochastic gradient descent, which doesn't even seem possible. I will take a look at debugging this however.